# Airbnb throws errors instead of warnings

Tags: reactjs, webpack, eslint, eslint-config-airbnb

I have an issue with a airbnb linter config. Instead of giving warnings, `eslint` throws errors which causes the compilation to fail with a `failed to compile` error.

My guess is that the problem is connected with webpack and its loaders. It needs configuration. It must be somehow connected to emmiting Errors in webpack. The important part of my webpack looks like this:

```
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx|mjs)$/,
        enforce: 'pre',
        use: [
          {
            options: {
              formatter: eslintFormatter,
              eslintPath: require.resolve('eslint'),
            },
            loader: require.resolve('eslint-loader'),
          },
        ],
        include: paths.appSrc,
      },
      {
        oneOf: [
          {
            test: [/\.bmp$/, /\.gif$/, /\.jpe?g$/, /\.png$/],
            loader: require.resolve('url-loader'),
            options: {
              limit: 10000,
              name: 'static/media/[name].[hash:8].[ext]',
            },
          },
          {
            test: /\.(js|jsx|mjs)$/,
            include: paths.appSrc,
            loader: require.resolve('babel-loader'),
            options: {

              cacheDirectory: true,
            },
          },
          {
            test: /\.css$/,
            use: [
              require.resolve('style-loader'),
              {
                loader: require.resolve('css-loader'),
                options: {
                  importLoaders: 1,
                },
              },
              {
                loader: require.resolve('postcss-loader'),
                options: {
                  ident: 'postcss',
                  plugins: () => [
                    require('postcss-flexbugs-fixes'),
                    autoprefixer({
                      browsers: [
                        '>1%',
                        'last 4 versions',
                        'Firefox ESR',
                        'not ie < 9', // React doesn't support IE8 anyway
                      ],
                      flexbox: 'no-2009',
                    }),
                  ],
                },
              },
            ],
          },

          {
            exclude: [/\.(js|jsx|mjs)$/, /\.html$/, /\.json$/, /\.sass$/, /\.scss$/],
            loader: require.resolve('file-loader'),
            options: {
              name: 'static/media/[name].[hash:8].[ext]',
            },
          },
          {
              test: /\.scss$/,
              exclude: /node_modules/,
              use: [
                  'style-loader',
                  'css-loader',
                  'sass-loader',
                  {
                      loader: 'sass-resources-loader',
                      options: {
                          resources: ['./src/styles/modules/_variables.scss'],
                      },
                  },
              ],
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  ...
```

Comment: You could remove the linting from webpack as it's not necessary to build, it's just good practice to fix the linting errors.

Comment: You mean to remove this part?     {
        test: /\.(js|jsx|mjs)$/,
        enforce: 'pre',
        use: [
          {
            options: {
              formatter: eslintFormatter,
              eslintPath: require.resolve('eslint'),
            },
            loader: require.resolve('eslint-loader'),
          },
        ],
        include: paths.appSrc,
      },

Comment: yes I mean this part

Comment: Thank you, I'll try that :)